# How to use Http instead of default gRPC for google monitoring API

Tags: java, grpc, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring

I am trying to use google monitoring API to get stackdriver metric by using java client library. My code are following:

```
MetricServiceSettings{executorProvider=I> ProjectName name = ProjectName.of(projectId)

// Restrict time to last 'cpuCheckRange' minutes
long startMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() - MS_IN_MIN * cpuCheckRange - 1
TimeInterval interval = TimeInterval.newBuilder()
        .setStartTime(Timestamps.fromMillis(startMillis))
        .setEndTime(Timestamps.fromMillis(System.currentTimeMillis()))
        .build()

Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newBuilder()
        .setAlignmentPeriod(Duration.newBuilder().setSeconds(SEC_IN_MIN * cpuCheckRange).build())
        .setPerSeriesAligner(Aggregation.Aligner.ALIGN_MEAN)
        .build()

ListTimeSeriesRequest.Builder requestBuilder = ListTimeSeriesRequest.newBuilder()
        .setName(name.toString())
        .setFilter("metric.type=\"spanner.googleapis.com/instance/cpu/utilization\" resource.type=\"spanner_instance\" resource.label.\"instance_id\"=\"$instanceId\"")
        .setInterval(interval)
        .setAggregation(aggregation)

ListTimeSeriesRequest request = requestBuilder.build()

TimeSeries timeSeries = null
MetricServiceClient metricServiceClient = null
try {

    metricServiceClient = MetricServiceClient.create()
    ListTimeSeriesPagedResponse response = metricServiceClient.listTimeSeries(request)

    for (TimeSeries ts : response.iterateAll()) {
        MonitoredResource resource = ts.getResource()
        Metric metric = ts.getMetric()

        if (metric.getType() == "spanner.googleapis.com/instance/cpu/utilization"
                && resource.getType() == "spanner_instance"
                && resource.getLabelsOrDefault("project_id", "") == projectId
                && resource.getLabelsOrDefault("instance_id", "") == instanceId) {
            timeSeries = ts
            break
        }
    }
} finally {
    if (metricServiceClient != null) {
        metricServiceClient.close()
    }
}
```

It is working locally, but for some reasons when I run it in jenkins inside docker container:

```
docker.image('katalonstudio/katalon:6.1.5').inside('-u root') {
............               
}
```

I get error:

```
com.google.api.gax.rpc.DeadlineExceededException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: deadline exceeded after 19999685365ns. [buffered_nanos=19999833833, waiting_for_connection
```

I assume that there is some connectivity issue related to gRPC. So how can I use http instead of gRPC for this API? or any other suggestions?

Environment details:

1. code running inside docker container 'katalonstudio/katalon:6.1.5'
2. dependency:

   compile 'io.cucumber:cucumber-picocontainer:3.0.2'
   compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
   compile 'org.jdom:jdom2:2.0.6'
   compile 'jaxen:jaxen:1.1.6'
   compile 'org.apache.ant:ant-jsch:1.10.5'
   compile 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-monitoring:1.90.0'
   compile 'io.netty:netty-all:4.1.3.Final'

Stacktrace:

```
22:33:29  com.google.api.gax.rpc.DeadlineExceededException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: deadline exceeded after 19999701924ns. [buffered_nanos=19999820820, waiting_for_connection]
22:33:29    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptionFactory.createException(ApiExceptionFactory.java:51)
22:33:29    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:72)
22:33:29    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:60)
22:33:29    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcExceptionCallable$ExceptionTransformingFuture.onFailure(GrpcExceptionCallable.java:97)
22:33:29    at com.google.api.core.ApiFutures$1.onFailure(ApiFutures.java:68)
22:33:29    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$CallbackListener.run(Futures.java:1365)
22:33:29    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:399)
22:33:29    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:973)
22:33:29    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:821)
22:33:29    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:685)
22:33:29    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$GrpcFuture.setException(ClientCalls.java:515)
22:33:29    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$UnaryStreamToFuture.onClose(ClientCalls.java:490)
22:33:29    at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39)
22:33:29    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23)
22:33:29    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40)
22:33:29    at io.grpc.internal.CensusStatsModule$StatsClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusStatsModule.java:700)
22:33:29    at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39)
22:33:29    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23)
22:33:29    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40)
22:33:29    at io.grpc.internal.CensusTracingModule$TracingClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusTracingModule.java:399)
22:33:29    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:510)
22:33:29    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$300(ClientCallImpl.java:66)
22:33:29    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.close(ClientCallImpl.java:630)
22:33:29    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.access$700(ClientCallImpl.java:518)
22:33:29    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:692)
22:33:29    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:681)
22:33:29    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
22:33:29    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
22:33:29    at ?.Customers exists in the system(/tmp/katalon_execute/project/Include/features/OCS_SPANNER_diameter_event.feature:5)
22:33:29    Suppressed: com.google.api.gax.rpc.AsyncTaskException: Asynchronous task failed
22:33:29        at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptions.callAndTranslateApiException(ApiExceptions.java:57)
22:33:29        at com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnaryCallable.call(UnaryCallable.java:112)
22:33:29        at com.google.cloud.monitoring.v3.MetricServiceClient.listTimeSeries(MetricServiceClient.java:995)
22:33:29        at com.google.cloud.monitoring.v3.MetricServiceClient$listTimeSeries$0.call(Unknown Source)
22:33:29        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
22:33:29        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
22:33:29        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
22:33:29        at com.optiva.CommonStepDefinition.getSpannerCpuUsage(CommonStepDefinition.groovy:744)
22:33:29        at com.optiva.CommonStepDefinition.checkSpannerCpuUsage(CommonStepDefinition.groovy:786)
22:33:29        at com.optiva.CommonStepDefinition.assertCustomers(CommonStepDefinition.groovy:117)
22:33:29        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
22:33:29        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
22:33:29        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
22:33:29        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
22:33:29        at cucumber.runtime.Utils$1.call(Utils.java:26)
22:33:29        at cucumber.runtime.Timeout.timeout(Timeout.java:16)
22:33:29        at cucumber.runtime.Utils.invoke(Utils.java:20)
22:33:29        at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaStepDefinition.execute(JavaStepDefinition.java:48)
22:33:29        at cucumber.runtime.PickleStepDefinitionMatch.runStep(PickleStepDefinitionMatch.java:50)
22:33:29        at cucumber.runner.TestStep.executeStep(TestStep.java:55)
22:33:29        at cucumber.runner.TestStep.run(TestStep.java:42)
22:33:29        at cucumber.runner.PickleStepTestStep.run(PickleStepTestStep.java:53)
22:33:29        at cucumber.runner.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:47)
22:33:29        at cucumber.runner.Runner.runPickle(Runner.java:44)
22:33:29        at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runFeature(Runtime.java:120)
22:33:29        at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:106)
22:33:29        at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:35)
22:33:29        at cucumber.api.cli.Main$run.call(Unknown Source)
22:33:29        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
22:33:29        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
22:33:29        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
22:33:29        at
```

Comment: Experiencing this issue too. Works when running on my dev machine in IntelliJ IDEA, doesn't work running on my dev machine in a Docker container. Sometimes I get this error, sometimes I get one related to metadata for credentials. Also doesn't work in a Docker container deployed to IBM Cloud Code Engine. Works fine when run in Google Cloud Run though, in which case I don't set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS env var, so that it picks up the service account I set as I deployed the Cloud Run service.

Answer (score 0):

This link talks about both REST and grpc https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/v3/

But Java client library and gRPC should work (and preferred?) so it will be better to debug this since I don't see any difference between grpc and REST in terms of connectivity requirements (except http2 vs http). Are you issuing your curl from the docker container's shell to ensure connectivity from there?

Comment: yes, I try to execute "curl monitoring.googleapis.com:443 " inside docker, and some data are returned. Besides that I try to use proxy as suggested in https://medium.com/google-cloud/accessing-google-cloud-apis-though-a-proxy-fe46658b5f2a. I tried to add netty-all in dependency as suggested in https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/issues/1430. All these did not help

Answer (score 0):

I'm using cloud monitoring api from inside a cloud run service and I observe frequent deadline exceeded errors myself:

```
com.google.api.gax.rpc.DeadlineExceededException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: deadline exceeded after 12.900875773s. [buffered_nanos=14900102827, waiting_for_connection]
at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptionFactory.createException(ApiExceptionFactory.java:51)
at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:72) 
at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:60) 
at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcExceptionCallable$ExceptionTransformingFuture.onFailure(GrpcExceptionCallable.java:97) 
at com.google.api.core.ApiFutures$1.onFailure(ApiFutures.java:68) 
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$CallbackListener.run(Futures.java:1072) 
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.DirectExecutor.execute(DirectExecutor.java:30) 
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:1164) 
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:958) 
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:749) 
at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$GrpcFuture.setException(ClientCalls.java:522) 
at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$UnaryStreamToFuture.onClose(ClientCalls.java:497) 
at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:426) 
at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$500(ClientCallImpl.java:66) 
at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$1CloseInContext.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:416) 
at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37) 
at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123) 
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) 
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) 
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) 
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) 
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) 
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

Suppressed: com.google.api.gax.rpc.AsyncTaskException: Asynchronous task failed
at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptions.callAndTranslateApiException(ApiExceptions.java:57) 
at com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnaryCallable.call(UnaryCallable.java:112) 
at com.google.cloud.monitoring.v3.MetricServiceClient.createTimeSeries(MetricServiceClient.java:1145) 
at org.mernst.metrics.ExporterModule$1.lambda$runOneIteration$3(ExporterModule.java:98)
```

Trying again from the same task will often make it work.
Sometimes it works right away in a freshly started task.

com.google.cloud:google-cloud-monitoring:1.100.0, default client options.